# How to make win32 console recognize ANSI/VT100 escape sequences in `c`?

Tags: c, windows, terminal, ncurses, ansi-escape

I'm building a lightweight version of the ncurses library. So far, it works pretty well with VT100-compatible terminals, but win32 console fails to recognise the `\033` code as the beginning of an escape sequence:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include "term.h"

int main(void) {
  puts(BOLD COLOR(FG, RED) "Bold text" NOT_BOLD " is cool!" CLEAR);
  return 0;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

What needs to be done on the `C code` level, in order that the ANSI.SYS driver is loaded and the ANSI/VT100 escape sequences recognized?

Comment: there is `colorama` module for Python: ["On Windows, Colorama strips these ANSI characters from stdout and converts them into equivalent win32 calls for colored text. On other platforms, Colorama does nothing."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python#comment3901803_3332860)

Comment: Please notice that the rules of the game have changed drastically as of recent versions of Windows 10.

Comment: FYI, in latest Windows 10, you can enable ANSI in conhost via the following reghack -- in `HKCU\Console` create a `DWORD` named `VirtualTerminalLevel` and set it to `0x1`; then restart cmd.exe. -- You can test it with the following powershell `"?[1;31mele ?[32mct ?[33mroni ?[35mX ?[36mtar ?[m".Replace('?', [char]27);`.

Comment: upd
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#example-of-select-anniversary-update-features
here how it could be enabled without editing registry, and possibly breaking other applications

Comment: ANSI.SYS is a thing I don't see since the WIN98 days.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 Your suggestion doesn't appear to work with Windows 10 V22H2 (OS Build 19045.2604). Ugh! MS!

Comment: Maybe same question as [batch file - How to echo with different colors in the Windows command line - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048509/how-to-echo-with-different-colors-in-the-windows-command-line).

Comment: Plz always specify the language you are trying to attempt since without it there can be multiple answers in multiple languages. And different languages have different ways to handle 1Ansi escape sequence`

Comment: @VinodSrivastav No, ISO / DEC VT-100 terminal escape sequences is a protocol, it's the "language" itself.

Comment: @JohanBoulé Are you telling us https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code is a language ? Kindly enlighten how you classified it as language and not encoding. BTW the comment was there as the Q was not tagged with a language even when the code is from `c` and i see answers from python and other languages.

Comment: @VinodSrivastav Yes, this is what I said and meant, it defines display instructions formatted/encoded in a certain way as to be interpreted by the video terminal hardware or software emulating it. That's a display language, just like Postscript or HTML. The OP posted some C code but it's important to understand that C is irrelevant to be problem. On Windows, terminal duty isn't handled by ANSI.SYS anymore but by the conhost.exe process, which is initialized with the standard sequence interpreter turned off by default, because MS is fearful of corner cases breaking legacy (cr)apps.

Comment: @JohanBoulé I am failing to understand why they embeded an interpreter in the terminal hardware which works even with my TV.  But it's all about ANSI escape code `\033` , `\x1b` or as unicode `\u001b[38` all that matters is the way your program passes the message. For the OP it should work as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences  as cmd.exe disables VT mode before starting other programs which is different then python code here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70599663/3057246 . That's why C is relevent to OP.

Comment: @VinodSrivastav Hmmm, unlike a TV, a hardware terminal doesn't receive video signal, it receives display instructions. I think a good analogy is a Postscript printer.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

[UPDATE] For latest Windows 10 please read useful contribution by @brainslugs83, just below in the comments to this answer.

While for versions before `Windows 10 Anniversary Update`:

ANSI.SYS has a restriction that it can run only in the context of the MS-DOS sub-system under Windows 95-Vista.

Microsoft KB101875 explains how to enable ANSI.SYS in a command window, **but it does not apply to Windows NT**. According to the article: [we all love colors](http://blog.mmediasys.com/2010/11/24/we-all-love-colors/), modern versions of Windows do not have this nice ANSI support.

Instead, Microsoft created a lot of functions, but this is far from your need to operate ANSI/VT100 escape sequence.

For a more detailed explanation, see the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code):

> ANSI.SYS also works in NT-derived systems for 16-bit legacy programs executing under the NTVDM.
>
> The Win32 console does not natively support ANSI escape sequences at all. Software such as [Ansicon](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon) can however act as a wrapper around the standard Win32 console and add support for ANSI escape sequences.

So I think **ANSICON**  by Jason Hood is your solution. It is written in [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Language), supports 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows, and [the source is available](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon).

Also I found some other similar question or post which ultimately have been answered to use ANSICON:

- [How to load ANSI escape codes or get coloured file listing in WinXP cmd shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946546/how-to-load-ansi-escape-codes-or-get-coloured-file-listing-in-winxp-cmd-shell)
- [how to use ansi.sys in windows 7](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/how-to-use-ansisys-in-windows-7/86d06a2a-33d9-45d9-88c4-a7917b46392d)
- [How can I get cmd.exe to display ANSI color escape sequences?](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070402210230AA8VFEy)
- [ansi color in windows shells](http://jasonkarns.com/blog/ansi-color-in-windows-shells/)
- [enable ansi colors in windows command prompt](http://www.liferay.com/it/web/igor.spasic/blog/-/blogs/enable-ansi-colors-in-windows-command-prompt)

Comment: I once did a hack to make ANSI work in Windows XP without any thirdparty tools https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.msdos.batch.nt/YZnoq80Mcds

Comment: How times change ;) In Windows 10 Anniversary Update and beyond, Windows Console was updated with pretty solid support for ANSI/VT sequences, and in Creators Update, was updated to support 24-bit RGB colors too: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/09/22/24-bit-color-in-the-windows-console

Comment: Answer updated according to Rich Turner contribution

Comment: @Simon thanks, I removed the link because it doesn't work btw there is an [archived version of kb/101875 here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130825002608/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/101875)

Comment: FYI, in latest Windows 10, you can enable ANSI in conhost via the following reghack -- in `HKCU\Console` create a `DWORD` named `VirtualTerminalLevel` and set it to `0x1`; then restart cmd.exe. -- You can test it with the following powershell `"?[1;31mele ?[32mct ?[33mroni ?[35mX ?[36mtar ?[m".Replace('?', [char]27);`.

Comment: Thanks @brainslugs83 - Answer updated to cite your comment

Answer (score 40):

Starting from Windows 10 TH2 (v1511), `conhost.exe` and `cmd.exe` support ANSI and VT100 Escape Sequences out of the box (although [they have to be enabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt638032(v=vs.85).aspx)).

See [my answer over at superuser](https://superuser.com/a/1050078/166203) for more details.

Comment: The 105xx builds was the only builds having VT100 sequences enabled by default. In previous and later builds it's disabled by default cause it was enabled by mistake. See here for the explanation https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/15617610--re-enable-enable-virtual-terminal-processing-by

Comment: FYI, in latest Windows 10, you can enable ANSI in conhost via the following reghack -- in `HKCU\Console` create a `DWORD` named `VirtualTerminalLevel` and set it to `0x1`; then restart cmd.exe. -- You can test it with the following powershell `"?[1;31mele ?[32mct ?[33mroni ?[35mX ?[36mtar ?[m".Replace('?', [char]27);`.

Answer (score 29):

Base on @BrainSlugs83 you can activate on the current Windows 10 version via register, with this command line:

```
REG ADD HKCU\CONSOLE /f /v VirtualTerminalLevel /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

Comment: Is this supported in all Windows 10 versions ? Or available from a specific update ?

Comment: in the firsts version of Windows 10 is not supported, but in the currents one work fine.

Comment: I want to know the specific version that supported this.

Comment: @Youssef13 According to https://superuser.com/a/1300251/702169, first supporting version is build 16257.

Answer (score 19):

**For Python 2.7 the following script works for me fine with Windows 10 (v1607)**

```
import os

print '\033[35m'+'color-test'+'\033[39m'+" test end"
os.system('') #enable VT100 Escape Sequence for WINDOWS 10 Ver. 1607
print '\033[35m'+'color-test'+'\033[39m'+" test end"
```

*Result should be:*

```
[35mcolor-test[39m test end

color-test test end
```

Comment: That starts to look like black magic and no mention of how to turn off the console setting afterwards? curiously, it works for me, but unclear why from the magical empty string.

Comment: If you wrap the printed material in parentheses `(...)` this works in Python 3 on Windows 10 (v1703).  (i.e. `print('\033[35m'+'color-test'+'\033[39m'+" test end")`)

Comment: Does someone have a source or know what `os.system('')` changes to the console ?

Comment: `os.system('')` works apparently because of a bug in cmd.exe (cmd.exe enables VT mode, but doesn't disable it on exit). For more info, and better code to enable VT mode, see discussion on [issue 30075 on python.org](https://bugs.python.org/issue30075)

Comment: You end console codes that end with m by doing `\033[0m`. Or, if you want to reset the whole terminal, and clear the screen, do `\033c`.

Answer (score 18):

Starting from Windows 10, you can use `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` to enable ANSI escape sequences:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt638032(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 13):

If ANSICON is not acceptable since it requires you to install something on the system, a more lightweight solution that parses and translates the ANSI codes into the relevant [Win32 API console functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx) such as [SetConsoleTextAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

https://github.com/mattn/ansicolor-w32.c

Comment: Just for instance, you can recompile the app by using the `ParseAndPrintString` function directly.

Answer (score 8):

For coloring the cmd you need `Windows.h` and use `SetConsoleTextAttribute()` more details can be found in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: That's quite an unwieldy solution, not to mention the fact that this only allows for the coloring of a text - not the rest of ANSI.SYS codes. http://users.cybercity.dk/~bse26236/batutil/help/ANSI~S_S.HTM

Answer (score 7):

In lastest win10, it can be done by `SetConsoleMode(originMode | ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING)`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#example

Answer (score 5):

Maybe [ANSICON](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon) can help u

Just download and extract files, depending on your windows os: 32bit or 64bit

Install it with: `ansicon -i`

Answer (score 2):

I personally like [clink](https://mridgers.github.io/clink/). It not only processes ANSI codes, it also adds many other features so Windows Console behaves like *bash* (history, reverse history search, keyboard shortcuts, etc.):

> - The same line editing as Bash (from GNU's Readline library).
> - History persistence between sessions.
> - Context sensitive completion;
>
>   - Executables (and aliases).
>   - Directory commands.
>   - Environment variables
>   - Thirdparty tools; Git, Mercurial, SVN, Go, and P4.
> - New keyboard shortcuts;
>
>   - Paste from clipboard (**Ctrl-V**).
>   - Incremental history search (**Ctrl-R/Ctrl-S**).
>   - Powerful completion (**TAB**).
>   - Undo (**Ctrl-Z**).
>   - Automatic "cd .." (**Ctrl-PgUp**).
>   - Environment variable expansion (**Ctrl-Alt-E**).
>   - (press **Alt-H** for many more...)
> - Scriptable completion with Lua.
> - **Coloured and scriptable prompt.**
> - Auto-answering of the "*Terminate batch job?*" prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Ansi.sys (in the system32 folder) is an "MSDOS driver" provided as part of Windows XP, 2000, and earlier versions of NT.  In 2000 and XP, it is located in the system32 folder (I don't remember the structure of earlier versions of NT).  Programs that run in the DOS subsystem and use standard output can use ANSI.SYS just as they could running over MSDOS.

To load ansi.sys, you must use the device= or devicehigh= command in config, just as you would in MSDOS.  On Windows NT 5 (2K & XP), each copy of the DOS subsystem can be given a separate config file in the pif/shortcut (use the "advanced" button), and there is a default file called CONFIG.NT (also in the system32 folder), which is used if the pif/shortcut does not specify a special config file.

When ansi.sys is loaded correctly, mem /d will report that it is loaded. On earlier versions of NT, you can and must load a proper DOS environment to load ansi.sys, and ansi art will work at the prompt.  On Win 2K and XP, loading ansi.sys will have no effect on your "CMD prompt" because CMD is not a DOS program: it is a 32 bit Windows console program.  For some reason that I do not understand, on WinXP, even if you load a fixed copy of command.com using "command.com /p", the command prompt will not be ansi enabled: perhaps when you do it that way it only emulates loading command.com?

In any case, when you use an actual DOS version of command.com, ansi *is* enabled after being loaded: you can demonstrate it's use with a bit of ansi art like this:

```
command /c type ansiart.ans
```

(here is an example: http://artscene.textfiles.com/ansi/artwork/beastie.ans)

CONFIG.NT (in the system32 folder) contains an example of the syntax for loading device drivers.  You will need to be an Administrator to edit that default file, or you can make a copy of it.

On Win 2K and XP, the default "shortcut" for MSDOS is a .PIF file, not a .LNK file.  If you create a .lnk file to CMD, you won't be able to set special config and autoexec files, it will use the default CONFIG.NT. If you want to use a special config file for just one DOS application, you can make a copy of the "MSDOS shortcut", or you can make a copy of "_default.pif", found in your Windows folder.

Answer (score 2):

I found this tool to be working for my end.
[Microsoft Color Tool from GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/console/releases/tag/1708.14008)

Unzip the compressed file then open CMD with Administration permission.

Go to the folder where you unzip the file in CMD.

Then execute this command "`colortool -b scheme-name`"

The scheme-name needs to be replaced with any of these options below:

- campbell.ini
- campbell-legacy.ini
- cmd-legacy.ini
- deuternopia.itermcolors
- OneHalfDark.itermcolors
- OneHalfLight.itermcolors
- solarized_dark.itermcolors
- solarized_light.itermcolors

In my case, the command would be like this "`colortool -b solarized_dark.itermcolors`"

Click right on the console window and select Properties.

You don't need to change any value just click "OK" to save the setting. (You will notice that your font already contains colors).

[Console Property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obpfn.png)

Then restart your cmd or powerShell.

The ANSI color should be enabled and working with the color scheme you chose before.

Comment: I tried this and then docker-machine refused to connect.

Comment: I'm sorry for so long but the method above was never tested for docker.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue.  I installed [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) and that one solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow in Windows you just need to call any shell command first, rather call the `system` function. Just in start of your main method put `system("");`, and don't forget to include `stdlib.h`.

I noticed this when I looked at some of my old programs that also used ANSI codes to understand why they work, but my new code is not