# Clearing the terminal screen in a command-line Dart app

Tags: dart, dart-io

This one don't work (on Windows in a Cmd-Box):

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
    print("Hello, World!");

    Process.start('cls', [], runInShell: true).then((process) {
        stdout.addStream(process.stdout);
        stderr.addStream(process.stderr);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**EDIT**
This seems to have the answer why it doesn't work on windows [How to make win32 console recognize ANSI/VT100 escape sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142)

**ORIGINAL**

```dart
if(Platform.isWindows) {
  // not tested, I don't have Windows
  // may not to work because 'cls' is an internal command of the Windows shell
  // not an executeable
  print(Process.runSync("cls", [], runInShell: true).stdout); 
} else {
  print(Process.runSync("clear", [], runInShell: true).stdout);
}
```

or

```dart
print("\x1B[2J\x1B[0;0H"); // clear entire screen, move cursor to 0;0
print("xxx") // just to show where the cursor is
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_codes
```

or

```dart
for(int i = 0; i < stdout.terminalLines; i++) {
  stdout.writeln();
}
```

The cursor position is on the bottom then.
You have to add newlines after some output to move it to the top.

Comment: Thank you Günter for the help but your proposals are not woking.  
On 1. proposal i have the same result as in my solution. A curious character '?' was printed.  
On 2. "?[2J?[0;0H" was printed. It seems that Dart don't support such a notation.  
On 3. is actually the best solution but it dosn't clear the terminal but scrolls 'x' lines, so the terminal seems empty  
  
 I also tried this one, without success:  

`print(Process.runSync("cmd", ['C "cls"'], runInShell: true).stdout);`

Comment: I could verify that 2 worked on linux. Maybe the characters have to be encoded differently. I'll take a look tomorrow what else can be tried. 3 could be used but I know it's inconvenient. You have to add a lot of linefeeds after new output to move it on the top of the screen.

Comment: @eugen Would you mind adding a comment how you solved the problem? Did you use ANSICON?

Comment: Yes, i have to use the second solution with ANSICON. The simple 'cls' usage seems not working because of strange Windows 7 behavior. It doesn't work with Java too. Only in Ruby i can simple call system("cls"). Too bad ...

Comment: Confirmed that the first solution does not work on Windows 11. Second solution with print("\x1B[2J\x1B[0;0H"); is the one working fine.