# Dart: Move cursor in command-line app

Tags: dart

1. What methods are there to move the cursor in a command line app?
2. I've tried simpler things, such as using "\b", but that didn't work:

   `print("test\ba");`

   I expected the output `tesa` but I get `testa` (**\b** was ignored).

### Update

Regarding (2), that was the output in the *webstorm IDE*, however it worked fine in the normal OS X Terminal.

Comment: What effect did you expect `\b` to have?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer See updated answer please.

Comment: The WebStorm  console output window doesn't support terminal commands. Just found the issue. Should be fixed since two months https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16674

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux or OSX you can use ANSI sequences https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code. On Windows you are pretty much out of luck AFAIK. Take a look at https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/ansicolor for an example how to use ANSI codes.

See also this similar question [Clearing the terminal screen in a command-line Dart app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269769/clearing-the-terminal-screen-in-a-command-line-dart-app/21275519#21275519)