# ANSI-Coloring Console Output with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, console, ansi-escape

I try to generate colored console output using [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) with the following minimal C# program:

```
using System;

// test.cs
class foo {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("\x1b[36mTEST\x1b[0m");
    }
}
```

I am running [Ansicon](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon) v1.66 on Windows 7 x64 with csc.exe (*Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.6.0081.0*).

Colored output works fine in this configuration; Ansicon itself is working flawlessly.

To cross-check I use a node.js one-liner that is 100% equivalent to the C# program:

```
// test.js
console.log("\x1b[36mTEST\x1b[0m");
```

And, even more basic, a hand-crafted text file:

[image: text file hex editor screenshot]

Both of which which correctly do the expected thing: Print a **teal**-colored string "TEST":

[image]

Only the test.exe I built with csc prints something else. Why?

Comment: Its not really a valid escape code in C#, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx It looks like the string `\x1b` is turned into a non-printable character before output to the console, the rest of it is output as-is. If you want to try outputing the raw text, prepend the string with the `@` symbol, aka: `Console.WriteLine(@"\x1b[36mTEST\x1b[0m");`

Comment: @RonBeyer Of coursed this is a valid escape code. It's the ASCII ESC character.

Comment: @Tomalak How do you expect the ESC character to be printed?

Comment: By invalid I mean non-printable, any hex number is "valid".

Comment: I'm sorry to say it, but I am afraid that you will have to read up on how ANSI color codes work. (I provided the JS counter-example not without reason.)

Comment: I understand the color codes, and I understand what you are trying to do here, but the C# compiler is replacing \x1b with the ESC code during compilation, so its basically turning it into a unicode unprintable character before its ever output to the console. I'm not sure this is making it to the console the same way as the JS version.

Comment: That's exactly what node.js does.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your program needs to be compiled for `/platform:x64` if you use the AnsiCon x64 environment and with `/platform:x86` if you use the AnsiCon x86/32 bits version. The exact reason is a mystery...

**Originally I thought you need all this:**

You need to grab the StandardOutput and let the Console.WriteLine believe you write to a File instead of to a Console and use an ASCII encoding.

This is how it will work:

```
 var stdout = Console.OpenStandardOutput();
 var con = new StreamWriter(stdout, Encoding.ASCII);
 con.AutoFlush = true;
 Console.SetOut(con);

 Console.WriteLine("\x1b[36mTEST\x1b[0m");
```

The .Net Console.WriteLine uses an internal `__ConsoleStream` that checks if the `Console.Out` is as file handle or a console handle. By default it uses a console handle and therefor writes to the console by calling [WriteConsoleW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34073467/ansi-coloring-console-output-with-net). In the remarks you find:

> Although an application can use WriteConsole in ANSI mode to write ANSI characters, consoles do not support ANSI escape sequences. However, some functions provide equivalent functionality. For more information, see SetCursorPos, SetConsoleTextAttribute, and GetConsoleCursorInfo.

To write the bytes directly to the console without `WriteConsoleW` interfering a simple filehandle/stream will do which is achieved by calling `OpenStandardOutput`. By wrapping that stream in a `StreamWriter` so we can set it again with `Console.SetOut` we are done. The byte sequences are send to the OutputStream and picked up by AnsiCon.

Do notice that this is only useable with an applicable terminal emulator, like AnsiCon, as shown here:

[image]

Comment: ...unfortunately, it does not seem to work. After the change, the output of your program stays the same `[36m...TEST...[0m` for me (plus the visible replacement characters for the `\x1b`).

Comment: @Tomalak hmm, maybe it has something to do with the default encoding. In my experiment last night I first went down the route to get the ASCII encoded byte array of the test string and then do a Console.OpenStandardOutput().WriteByte(array,0, array.Length);  when that worked I reworked the stuff to my working example. Maybe the streamwriter needs an encoding?

Comment: I'm at work atm and don't have a dev box ready, I'll revisit this tonight.

Comment: @Tomalak I found the issue. I had to add the Encoding.ASCII to the streamwriter again. I must have missed that I removed the encoding but didn't recompile, sorry for the hassle.

Comment: Nope, still no dice. It looks as if AnsiCon would be entirely circumvented. When I run this on an unarmed cmd.exe the output is exactly the same. Can you post the exact source code that works for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97019/discussion-between-rene-and-tomalak).

Comment: In case you don't want to limit yourself with stand set of colors, look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/76005078/3057246

Comment: Working well in 2023 at least on Linux. In just the final line works well in F# `System.Console.WriteLine("\x1b[36mTEST\x1b[0m");;`

Comment: @PhilT yeah, most terminals in Linux have been superior over the Windows mess for ages. Windows Terminal is now playing catch-up and getting there. Some background in this scott hanselman video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tuhzVDc0Slg

Answer (score 22):

I've created a [small plugin](https://github.com/silkfire/Pastel) (available on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pastel)) that allows you to easily wrap your strings in ANSI color codes. Both foreground and background colors are supported.

[image]

It works by extending the `String` object, and the syntax is very simple:

```
"colorize me".Pastel("#1E90FF");
```

After which the string is ready to be printed to the console.

```cs
Console.WriteLine("colorize me".Pastel("#1E90FF"));
```

Comment: Wow, it just works

Answer (score 1):

Using Ansi sequences worked out of the box for me if I was running my code from Visual Studio (F5/Play). Running from the console though it wouldn't work.

If you are still struggling with this, this is what solved the problem for me:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    // P/Invoke declarations
    private const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;
    private const uint ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING = 4;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool GetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, out uint lpMode);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, uint dwMode);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Get the handle to the standard output stream
        var handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

        // Get the current console mode
        uint mode;
        if (!GetConsoleMode(handle, out mode))
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Failed to get console mode");
            return;
        }

        // Enable the virtual terminal processing mode
        mode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
        if (!SetConsoleMode(handle, mode))
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Failed to set console mode");
            return;
        }

        // Now you can use ANSI escape codes to colorize your output
        Console.WriteLine("\x1b[91mThis should be colorful\x1b[0m");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this question today and I could not get the accepted answer to work. After some research on my own I found an answer which will get it to work.

It is a pitty, but we need to go very low level on this and call the Windows API directly. For this purpose I'm using the `PInvoke.Kernel32` NuGet for convenience reasons, but if it is too heavy-weight for you, you might create the P\Invoke mapping yourself.

The following method illustrates, how one may activate the ANSI Codes:

```
bool TryEnableAnsiCodesForHandle(Kernel32.StdHandle stdHandle)
{
    var consoleHandle = Kernel32.GetStdHandle(stdHandle);
    if (Kernel32.GetConsoleMode(consoleHandle, out var consoleBufferModes) &&
        consoleBufferModes.HasFlag(Kernel32.ConsoleBufferModes.ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING))
        return true;
    
    consoleBufferModes |= Kernel32.ConsoleBufferModes.ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
    return Kernel32.SetConsoleMode(consoleHandle, consoleBufferModes);
}
```

To enable it for StdOut you call it like:

```
TryEnableAnsiCodesForHandle(Kernel32.StdHandle.STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
```

If the method returns true, the ANSI Codes are enabled, else they are not.

The solution uses the very low level Windows API `GetConsoleMode` and `SetConsoleMode` to check if the control buffer mode `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` is set, and if it is not set it tries to set the mode.

Comment: It sounds like you're not using Ansicon, but native Windows console coloring?

Comment: Actually, I don't know nothing about the internals of the solution. But in the further program I am using `Console.WriteLine` and `Console.Error.WriteLine` and it works.

Comment: I checked PowerShell, CMD and Rider Terminal. They all work with this solution.

Comment: They probably won't in Windows 7 cmd.exe (which this question was about specifically), because native support for color codes was added to Windows later. So this might solve your issue, but it's not really an answer to the question, because your setup is different.

Comment: See this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/76005078/3057246 it's a color mixer and not limited to standard set