# Grunt + TFS build output format

Tags: tfs, gruntjs, build-process

I'm using grunt in my project to run my unit test (use karma), test coverage, code analysis (tslint), ... I easily include my grunt task into my TFS build proccess template, thanks to activity 'Invoke process':

[image]

WriteBuildMessage only print sdtOutput msg and i got the following result :

[image: grunt output TFS]

Why output format like this : ←[31m>> ←[39m ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These codes are [ANSI escape code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), however, windows terminal doesn't understand them.

Here is a related question : [How to make win32 console recognize ANSI/VT100 escape sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/how-to-make-win32-console-recognize-ansi-vt100-escape-sequences)

Comment: A note: You should be able to use the command line switch `--no-color`, which will remove some, if not all, of the escape codes.

Comment: This what i did (use --no-color) but this is not working, i always get weird char, i'm gonna try espcape codes :)

Comment: It's not that the windows terminal doesn't understand them, it's that when you redirect the console output to a file you have the escape sequences in the file.

Answer (score 0):

So i try --no-color option but this not working. Finally i add the foolowing line to my Gruntfile.js : `grunt.file.defaultEncoding = 'utf8';`

This works perfectly ! Thanks for your help everybody.