# Python Colorama Escape Sequences on Linux compatible with Windows Wordpad

Tags: linux, windows, ascii, ansi-escape, wordpad

I'm using Python Colorama on a Linux system to print stdout to the terminal in color. I use the Linux 'tee' command to also capture this output to a file. When the script is done, it emails the captured text file, including the escape sequences, to an email address that I check on Windows. The email has the text file as an attachement, and if I open it with Windows Wordpad I see this:

```
 [37m [45m [1m**************************************** [40m
 [37m [45m*** Welcome to the QtHttp Test Suite *** [40m
 [37m [45m**************************************** [40m
```

Here is a screenshot of the terminal in Linux:

[image]

If I 'cat' the file in Linux, it shows the color in the terminal.

How can I open the file in Windows so that it honors the escape sequences and shows the text file in color?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just as with Linux, you could `cat` the file, given an appropriate terminal to interpret the characters.  (You do not actually need a *terminal* - some other programs will do this, e.g., the manpage filter of vi-like-emacs).

The question has been asked before.  Here are some links

- [How to make win32 console recognize ANSI/VT100 escape sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/how-to-make-win32-console-recognize-ansi-vt100-escape-sequences)
- [How to enable ANSI escape codes in Windows cmd?](https://serverfault.com/questions/106028/how-to-enable-ansi-escape-codes-in-windows-cmd)
- [Windows console with ANSI colors handling](https://superuser.com/questions/413073/windows-console-with-ansi-colors-handling)

However, if you are developing on Windows as well, the first place to look would be something like [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/), [MinGW](http://mingw.org/) or [MSYS2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/).