# Laravel 5.2 artisan command list showing unformatted data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have a windows machine and using laravel 5.2. when i am running php artisan list command it display all command but appending some unformatted data in front of result. can you please help me on this.

Attaching console result screenshot

[image]

Comment: Native Windows command line doesn't support [ANSI colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors)

Comment: Use artisan inside one of the following: [Git BASH](https://git-for-windows.github.io/), [cmder](http://cmder.net/), [babun](http://babun.github.io/), [Ansicon](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon)

Comment: take a look at [laravel artisan commands colors not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29422276/laravel-artisan-commands-colors-not-showing)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel artisan commands colors not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29422276/laravel-artisan-commands-colors-not-showing)

Comment: But when i am installing laravel versions 5.4 then it shows properly