# How do i clear screen in Erlang in Windows

Tags: windows, erlang

I am using Windows as OS and installed Erlang 16B. How do i clear my screen?

I have already **tried** :

> clrscr().
>
> clearscreen().
>
> cls().

But failed each and every time.

(May be very simple question but i am not able to find the solution.)

Answer (score 6):

Type the below command to your erlang shell.

`io:format(os:cmd(clear)).`

And off you go :)

Comment: I like this better than doing `io:format("\033[2J").`, because it also takes the current line to the top of the screen rather than at the bottom. Thanks!
P.S. This was on OSX + iterm.

Answer (score 2):

The author of the following link/answer suggests to use io:format.

http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2014-November/081939.html

Write your own function call:

```
clear() ->
    io:format("\033[2J").
```

Comment: That is unlikely to work in a *Windows* console as OP appears to be requesting, but only in something like a Cygwin or MinGW shell (which use a terminal emulator).

Comment: @ThomasDickey Yes, I agree! Every time I read the word windows, my eyes get blind. ;-) Here is a usefull link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/how-to-make-win32-console-recognize-ansi-vt100-escape-sequences