# How do I manipulate console cursor position in dotnet core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

How do I manipulate console cursor position in dotnet core?

As far as I can see in https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Console/src/System/Console.cs there is no way to manipualte cursor position.

Does it mean that it's impossible on windows and will be possible on linux via ANSI escape sequences?

Comment: You want to move and control the mouse etc?

Comment: @Slashy the console cursor is the .... cursor in the console window. The OP knows what he's asking. The escape sequences should also work in Windows BTW

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The Windows Console does not support ANSI escape sequences per se. [You need to load some custom "driver"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16799175/21567).

Comment: @Christian.K duh - it's been 20 years since I had to position the console cursor! This doesn't mean the escape sequences can't be used though, if a .NET core application runs on Linux. A non-Core application on Windows, or Mono on Linux wouldn't need them either, it could use the positioning methods

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I was refering to the part where you state that escape sequences "should also work in Windows BTW". Not to nitpick, but to prevent the OP from going this road in vain. ;-)  So in summary, currently, he'd have to use escape sequences for Linux and the Win32 API (like wrapped in the full .NET framework) on Windows. Best wrapped behind some compat layer of course.

Comment: @Christian.K it looks like .NET Core already has part of this implementation, with platform specific overrides ....

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah. But it looks like it is tucked away in the _internal_ `ConsolePal`-class with no public API surface. Strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `ConsolePal` class you have `private static IntPtr OutputHandle`(that is the handle of the console on which you want to move the cursor), so int this class you have to expose a method to set the cursor position.
In this method you have to call system API `SetConsoleCursorPosition(IntPtr hConsoleOutput, COORD cursorPosition);`.
`COORD` is:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct COORD
{
    internal short X;
    internal short Y;
}
```

You can add `DllImport` of the previous method in `Interop.mincore` class (because it seems that is here where system `DllImport` are made), so somewhere where you want you can:

```
internal partial class Interop
{
    internal partial class mincore
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
        internal static extern bool SetConsoleCursorPosition(IntPtr hConsoleOutput, COORD cursorPosition);
    }
}
```

The method to expose in ConsolePal can look like this:

```
public static void SetCursorPosition(int left, int top)
{
    IntPtr consoleOutputHandle = OutputHandle;
    COORD cursorPosition = new COORD {
        X = (short) left,
        Y = (short) top
    };
    Interop.mincore.SetConsoleCursorPosition(consoleOutputHandle, cursorPosition;
}
```

**Note:** add to the method some input check and some check on `Interop.mincore.SetConsoleCursorPosition` returned value

And in `Console` class simply expose a method that call `ConsolePal.SetCursorPosition`

```
public static void SetCursorPosition(int left, int top)
{
     ConsolePal.SetCursorPosition(left, top);
}
```

I didn't test the code above so it may contain errors.

**Edit**

As @Jcl stated, it may not be welcome to use a custom version of .NET. In this case you can write a simple class to move the cursor(even this solution is only for Windows):

```
static class MyAwesomeConsoleExtensions
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool SetConsoleCursorPosition(IntPtr hConsoleOutput, COORD cursorPosition);
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct COORD
    {
        internal short X;
        internal short Y;
    }
    private const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;

    public static void SetCursorPos(int left, int top)
    {
        IntPtr consoleOutputHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        COORD cursorPosition = new COORD
        {
            X = (short)left,
            Y = (short)top
        };
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(consoleOutputHandle, cursorPosition);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not saying it's not supported (it indeed is), but going native with `DllImport` and the Win32 Api on .NET Core might not be an all that good idea

Comment: This would only work on Windows. I guess the OP could use a Linux implementation (perhaps using ANSI sequences) in a different class, just like .NET core does with ConsolePal.Windows and ConsolePal.Unix.cs

Comment: @Jcl check the repository. ConsolePal *is* a Core class with platform-specific specializations. ConsolePal.Windows.cs does uses Interop and ConsolePal.Unix uses POSIX calls

Comment: Uhm... but ConsolePal is an internal class. How should he use that (short of using reflection of course).

Comment: Oh yes, I know it's indeed supported. Just feel (personal feel) that native calls should be avoided whenever possible outside the actual framework for Core

Comment: @Jcl `DllImport` are widely [used](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=DllImport&type=Code) in .NET Core. I'm suggesting to add this call in ConsolePal.Windows.cs, so platform specific, I don't think that this can lead troubles

Comment: @Christian.K I was assuming that he can recompile the core, so I suggested him to wrap the call to `ConsolePal.SetCursorPosition` in `Console` class (that is obviously public)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos My limited knowledge can help only on Windows environment. I hope that the community will help improving the answer with Linux/Unix part

Comment: @codroipo if I didn't think having calls to native code outside the framework  felt right, I'd feel much worse about having a *custom* build of net core for your app. Again, not saying your answer is wrong, or that it can't be done... it just doesn't *feel* right. But of course, this is just a personal subjective oppinion, not dogma. YMMV

Comment: You could always fork and make a feature/pull request, of course :-)

Comment: @Jcl I updated the answer with code that doesn't need core recompilation

Comment: @codroipo all things said, I'd be a supporter of that code for the "old" net framework... again, I'm just not keen (but let me repeat: *it's something personal*) of using `DllImport` on net core (outside the framework itself)... but it is indeed a solution (for Windows)

Comment: Solution "just for windows" is OK, as long as I can use ANSI escape characters for linux version.
Thanks!