# how to print VT100 escape sequences in c++ to windows terminal?

Tags: c++, vt100

I want to print the VT100 escape sequences as on given in this website http://www.climagic.org/mirrors/VT100_Escape_Codes.html to screen .I am using a windows10 PC. I don't really know much about them.

Comment: It is unlikely that the windows terminal will handle VT100 codes.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/how-to-make-win32-console-recognize-ansi-vt100-escape-sequences especially this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35864976/2193968