# Colored text in command prompt after "cls" but not before "cls"

Tags: python, windows-10, command-prompt, ansi-colors

I have a python program where I am trying to print "Hello" in colored text using ANSI codes in command prompt. When I print in normally, it is not working, it just prints ? and text, but when I print it after clearing the command prompt it works fine. Can some one explain this weird nature.

I searched for this but couldn't find anything about this nature. I am using Windows 10

The below code outputs `[0;32mHello[0m`

```py
print('\x1b[0;32m' + "Hello" + '\033[0m')
```

[image: no color]

whereas the below code outputs Hello in green color.

```py
os.system("cls")
print('\x1b[0;32m' + "Hello" + '\033[0m')
```

Right image is the output of the code shown above or in the left image
[image]    [image]

My expectation was that is gives either ansii or colored text in both the above codes, but actual output is different in both the cases

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: Could you please make a test with **sys**? This is the [code](https://gist.github.com/EsdrasXavier/699e263ed78333b4df6bdd7cab99da75)

Comment: @EsdrasXavier, I tested the code you gave me, it gave same output as shown in the images above and my python version is 3.7.2

Comment: Well, I did some research about it, and looks like this could be a Windows issue. What you can do is use colorama, seems to solve the windows issue converting the asc code for each windows version. Take a look at this [link](https://www.devdungeon.com/content/colorize-terminal-output-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make win32 console recognize ANSI/VT100 escape sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/how-to-make-win32-console-recognize-ansi-vt100-escape-sequences)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
os.system("")
print('\x1b[0;32m' + "Hello" + '\033[0m')
```

Comment: An explanation is required with the code, then only that will be called an answer.

Comment: This *is* an answer, imo. But it tends to be an answer which is not helpful without more explanation. You could easily add some more context: E.g. why the difference `os.system("")` vs. `os.system("cls")` in OPs question? How and why exactly will this solve the problem?

Comment: Sry, I wrote my comment in wrong section. I dint had enough 'reputaion' in stackoverflwo to (one needs atleast 50 reputaion) to write a comment. Thats why I wrote my comment in Answer section

Answer (score 0):

This must be an internal error in Windows 10. I tried to use Java to recreate your problem and came to the conclusion that this error can be fixed by [enabling the virtual terminal processor](https://superuser.com/a/1300251), which interprets ANSI characters using the software encoder, or you can just use the new Windows Terminal (it uses PowerShell as the default CLI).

**Hint:** This is the registry entry that enables the virtual terminal processor:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]
"VirtualTerminalLevel"=dword:00000001
```

If you don't want your users to address this issue by themselves, you can try these solutions:

1. You can try to directly write the bytes of the ANSI sequence to the console output stream (equivalent to `String.getBytes()` in Java), which should work on the Windows 10 Command Prompt.
2. You can run the `cls` command at the start of your program to get an unstable fix of the error.
3. You can use the `Windows` > `Console API` > [`SetConsoleMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/console/setconsolemode) method to temporarily enable the virtual terminal processor (`ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT: 0x0200`).