# How to have colored text displayed after converting script into a .exe?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a code that will create colored text for me. It works when I am testing the program within PyCharm, but when I convert the file to an exe using pyinstaller it gives me a weird printing output.

Code:

```
blue = lambda text: '\033[0;34m' + text + '\033[0m'
print(blue('Hello World'))
```

Output:

```
[0;34mHello World[0m
```

This code has to run on someone else's pc, so I can't really download any modules unless there is a way to bundle them with the exe. Is there something I am doing wrong? Is there a way to have color after converting into an exe?

Comment: Does your text console support ANSI coloring?

Comment: pycharm's internal console must support ANSI escape sequences, but when you run it from in a terminal as a standalone it's not supported. Windows `cmd` shell doesn't natively support it. There are add-ons for it that will but you'll have do installed and configure them manually.

Comment: See [How to make win32 console recognize ANSI/VT100 escape sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/how-to-make-win32-console-recognize-ansi-vt100-escape-sequences)

Comment: BTW named lambdas are bad practice. Use a `def` instead, or in this case, don't even bother rolling your own functions - use a library instead. BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: And yes you can bundle modules in an EXE. How to do that depends on the EXE maker you're using.