# How can I fix my problem with colored output in C

Tags: c

I want to print a colored sentence,
My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main()
{
    printf("\033[0;34m");
    printf("This is Blue"); 
    return 0;
}
```

And this is output:

```
[0;34mThis is Blue
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What compiler/terminal are you using?

Comment: The terminal is responsible to display colors. Which terminal are you using? Windows terminals don't handle colors for instance (both cmd and powershell).

Comment: If it's windows see [How to make win32 console recognize ANSI/VT100 escape sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/how-to-make-win32-console-recognize-ansi-vt100-escape-sequences)

Comment: An usual terminal does not need to provide the ability to do special colored output. If, it is due to a specific terminal. Also: Why do you think `"\033[0;34m"` is displaying anything blue, too? Did you seen it anywhere? More information please.

Comment: with the right terminal your program does the expected result, for instance an LX terminal under raspbian

Comment: Working as expected using `gcc` and `Cygwin`/`bash`.

Comment: Windows console can handle colours, but only via the [console API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletextattribute).

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine in VSCode in-built terminal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make win32 console recognize ANSI/VT100 escape sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/how-to-make-win32-console-recognize-ansi-vt100-escape-sequences)

Comment: You could also avoid the ANSI/VT codes by using a curses library (line ncurses or pdcurses).

Comment: Welcome to SO. SO works best if there is feedback from the authors of questions. Especially if there are questions about missing details in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your program does exactly what it is supposed to do: output what you tell it to to the console.

However, if you are expecting to see colors when sending ANSI/VT100 codes to the console the console must understand these codes.

You didn't mention what operating system and console you are using.

If it's Windows for example the console doesn't support ANSI/VT100 codes by default (to enable see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

If it Unix or Linux you may need to check what the TERM environment variable is set to and if that is supported by the console application you're using.

If you are using a remote console (like PuTTY on Windows) you may need to set the terminal type to `xterm-color`.
[image]