# ANSI Escape Color Codes from text file not printing properly

Tags: python, windows, msys

When trying to read text from a file where it contains ANSI escape color codes it just prints the color codes and does not show colors

This was both tested in Windows 10 and MSYS

Text File(title.txt):`\033[0;32m Example \033[0m`

Code:

```
def ShowText():
    ## Declare the path of the title
    titlePath = r'display\title.txt'

    ## Try to read the title from the given text
    try:
        ## Open the file in read mode
        f = io.open(titlePath, mode="r", encoding="ascii")
    
        ## Print the read text
        print(f.read())

    except (IOError, OSError) as e:
        print("Could not read text")
```

Text Output: `\033[0;32m Example \033[0m`

Print:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/se4MS.png

I also tried importing and initializing **colorama** and use **termcolor** **cprint** but the results are equal

Comment: The test can be reduced to `python3 -c "print('\033[0;32m Example \033[0m')"` which works fine under Linux. The problem is with Windows console. See [How to make win32 console recognize ANSI/VT100 escape sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16755142/95735).

Comment: You need to [enable virtual terminal processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode).

Comment: It could also of unescaping the string with: f.read().decode('unicode_escape')