# colored text without any module windows python

Tags: python, string, text, colors

I'm have windows 10.

I'm can print colored text in windows without any module? (like `colorama`)
if I run:

```
GREEN =  '\033[32m' 
print (GREEN + "This is some green text!")
```

then I got ←[32mThis is some green text!

why?

Comment: Which Windows "shell" are you using? (cmd, powershell, wsl bash?..)

Comment: cmd or powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla cmd.exe doesn't support ANSI escapes. Either use another terminal app (such as [Windows Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk70), [Conemu](https://conemu.github.io/) or [Cmder](https://cmder.net/)) or see [How to make win32 console recognize ANSI/VT100 escape sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/how-to-make-win32-console-recognize-ansi-vt100-escape-sequences) to turn on ANSI in vanilla cmd.

Comment: thanks. i was run this code to windows terminal and get colored text.