# VB.NET Console: Use ANSI Sequences (Console Virtual Terminal Sequences)

Tags: c#, c, vb.net, console, ansi-escape

I am trying to write a console app in VB.NET (VS Studio Community 2019 & .Net framework 4.8)
I cannot get it to display ANSI Escape sequences correctly.
I am aware of [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/how-to-make-win32-console-recognize-ansi-vt100-escape-sequences) and have applied it. (Makes no difference)

I am able to set colour using

```vb
Console.ResetColor()
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
```

and cursor positioning, using

```vb
Console.SetCursorPosition(origCol + x, origRow + y)
Console.Write(s)
```

When I try to do this

```vb
Console.WriteLine("\u001b[31mHello World!\u001b[0m")
```

It just prints it out raw without interpreting the ANSI Sequences.

`Console.OutputEncoding = Text.Encoding.XXX` only gives me limited options for XXX, including Ascii, UTF8, 16, 32 and Unicode.

I have gone over [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) article on "Console Virtual Terminal Sequences", which seems to be Microsoft's term for ANSI Codes. This article refers to [setConsoleMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode).

There is also this snippet of C, for which I can find no equivalent in vb.net

```
// Set output mode to handle virtual terminal sequences
    HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if (hOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    DWORD dwMode = 0;
    if (!GetConsoleMode(hOut, &dwMode))
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    dwMode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
    if (!SetConsoleMode(hOut, dwMode))
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }
```

I'm guessing that one of these two might be the answer to my problem, but I have no idea how to do anything with this info in VB.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question title indicates the programming is VB.net. Yet this statement is shown

```
Console.WriteLine("\u001b[31mHello World!\u001b[0m")
```

in which the C# style unicode escape sequence, **\u001b** is used.  VB does not support escape sequences.  A proper VB statement using string interpolation and the [ChrW Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.chrw?view=net-5.0) would be:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{ChrW(&H1B)}[31mHello World!{ChrW(&H1B)}[0m")
```

> There is also this snippet of C, for which I can find no equivalent in vb.net

This will require using the Platform Invoke (PInvoke) feature to call the native api functions.  A direct conversion of the snippet is wrapped in the `SetVT100Mode` method defined below. You can find the various constants in either the documentation or by looking at the examples at [Pinvoke.net](https://pinvoke.net/).

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Module Module1
  Private Const STD_INPUT_HANDLE As Int32 = -10
  Private Const STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE As Int32 = -11
  Private Const STD_ERROR_HANDLE As Int32 = -12
  Private ReadOnly INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE As New IntPtr(-1)
  Private Const ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING As UInt32 = &H4

  Sub Main()
    Const Esc As Char = ChrW(27)

    If SetVT100Mode() = 0 Then
      Console.WriteLine($"{Esc}[31mHello World!{Esc}[0m")
    End If

    Console.ReadLine()

  End Sub

  Private Function SetVT100Mode() As Int32
    Dim hOut As IntPtr = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
    If hOut = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE Then
      Return Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
    End If

    Dim mode As UInt32
    If Not GetConsoleMode(hOut, mode) Then
      Return Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
    End If

    mode = mode Or ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING
    If Not SetConsoleMode(hOut, mode) Then
      Return Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
    End If
    Return 0
  End Function

  <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
  Private Function GetConsoleMode(ByVal hConsoleHandle As IntPtr, ByRef lpMode As UInteger) As Boolean
  End Function

  <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
  Private Function SetConsoleMode(ByVal hConsoleHandle As IntPtr, ByVal dwMode As UInteger) As Boolean
  End Function

  <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
  Private Function GetStdHandle(ByVal nStdHandle As Integer) As IntPtr
  End Function

End Module
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you! The first issue you pointed out, using ChrW(&H1B), is a major leap forward for me. I have no idea why I haven't spotted that anywhere before!

Comment: Your "Pinvoke" code, I saved as a test program and it compiled and ran perfectly! Thank you once again.