# What does "←[37m" mean in the terminal when running Flask?

Tags: flask, terminal

When I type `flask run` and go to `127.0.0.1:5000/myfirstpage`, I can see the following output in my terminal:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Apr/2021 14:55:34] "←[37mGET /myfirstpage HTTP/1.1←[0m" 200 -
```

I understand that `127.0.0.1` is my localhost server, `myfirstpage` the path, `HTTP/1.1` the version of the hypertext transfer protocol and `200` the HTTP status code for 'successfully responded to request'.

But what do `←[37m` and `←[0m` stand for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks a lot like badly formatted terminal escape sequences.

According to https://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BuildyourownCommandLinewithANSIescapecodes.html

it is

```
White: \u001b[37m
Reset: \u001b[0m
```

also have a look at that [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#SGR_(Select_Graphic_Rendition)_parameters) from wikipedia

Comment: That makes sense. I am on Windows 10 and according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/16799175/11826257 the Win console does not support ANSI escape sequences.