# groff for Windows: man pages bad formatted when output in windows command prompt

Tags: windows, manpage, groff

From Windows command prompt I am using groff for Windows to display some man pages.

I can see that some characters are not being correctly outputted and in some case depending on the device being passed in as parameter I get some warnings.

For example:

1. groff -man -Tascii < mymanpage.1 | more
   The man page is displayed but with below warning and some characters not correctly displayed.

   Warning:
   :48: warning: can't find character with input code 226

   Also I get characters not correctly displayed:
   [image]
2. groff -man -Tutf8 < mymanpage.1 | more

   Even worse:
   [image]
3. groff -man -Tlatin1 < mymanpage.1 | more

   [image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/how-to-make-win32-console-recognize-ansi-vt100-escape-sequences

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the Windows terminal does not understand the escape codes. If `col` is available on your system, you might:

```
groff -man -Tascii  mymanpage.1 | col -b |more
```