# Colors not showing properly in Plink

Tags: ssh, cmd, tty, plink

I want to use the `-pw` parameter that is not included in the `ssh`, but `plink` does not handle the `$TERM` correctly as `←[46m←[30m` are displayed instead of their respective colors. Is this fixable and if so, how?

Comment: Some hints: `plink.exe` outputs by default to standard output stream what it captures from standard output stream of the remote machine. There are options to change the default behavior. Open the help of *PuTTY* by starting *PuTTY* and clicking on button __Help__ or double clicking on file `putty.chm` in program files directory of *PuTTY* containing also plink.exe and read the chapter __Chapter 7: Using the command-line connection tool Plink__ completely including __7.2.3 Plink command line options__ and __3.11.3 Standard command-line options__.

Comment: Then read the Wikipedia articles about [Windows Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Terminal) and [cmd.exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) as well as the Microsoft documentation page about [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences). The __Windows Terminal__ supports by default ESC sequences while __Windows Command Prompt__ (`cmd.exe`) does not by default, but that can be changed depending on version of Windows (= version of `cmd.exe`).

Comment: If you are interested in information for programmers about enabling support for console virtual terminal sequences, read for example the Stack Overflow page [How to make win32 console recognize ANSI/VT100 escape sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/) But if you are not a programmer and just want to know from a user's point of view how to do that, read for example [Enable ANSI escape sequence within Windows 10 console](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=9144). There are lots of web pages with similar information.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, Plink does not implement terminal emulation.

It's intended to be used for command automation. Not for an interactive terminal use.