# Escape Sequences for EXE

Tags: linux, windows, cmd, escaping, ansi-escape

I have some escape sequences in my config on my Linux machine that work fine, but for some reason, they are completely ignored in the Windows port of [Pianobar](https://github.com/PromyLOPh/pianobar).

What's interesting is it doesn't print the escape sequences to the display - it just seems to skip over them completely.

Goal is to clear the screen after each song is played.

Right now, my config reads as

```
format_msg_nowplaying = ^[[1E^[[2J^[[J^[[H %s
format_nowplaying_song = ^[[2;1H Now Playing: ^[[3;1H "%t" by %a
```

This works just fine on my Linux machine, but on the Windows port of the program, it seems to ignore the string entirely. It processes the `Now Playing:`  `"%t" by %a` but nothing else.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/how-to-make-win32-console-recognize-ansi-vt100-escape-sequences

Comment: Thank you so much.
I'm afraid I tried that. The escape sequences seem to work in a PS1 script, but not in the config.

Answer (score 0):

I received an email reply from the creator. They did not initially implement the escape codes, but a new release has them implemented:

> From: Michał Cichoń
> Sent: Sunday, October 9, 2022 8:27 AM
> To: Christopher Moore
> Subject: Re: Pianobar

> Hello Christopher,

> Well. I didn't implemented escape codes you are using. This is now done and you can use them without worries.
> Pleas keep in mint that in config you need to insert actual escape code not ^[ sequence.

> Please pick up today's release: https://github.com/thedmd/pianobar-windows/releases/tag/2022.10.09

> Cheers!