# Running code from Visual Studio debug window produces different results than running it from CMD

Tags: c

I wrote code to print the same text in 2 locations and it works until I insert the cursor movement line and while the code still runs, the result is garbled, the move command gets printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[] = "text"; // Declare string
    printf("%s", str);   // Print string
    printf("\033[4B");   // Move down 4 lines;
    printf("%s", str);   // Print string
    char ch = _getch();
}
```

VS Debug window prints it corrently:

```
text



    text
```

CMD prints

```
text←[4Btext
```

I tried installing .NET Framework and using  a different compiler (gcc to be specific) and even tried running this on 4 different machines, they all produced the same result.

Comment: It’s not a function of the compiler. It requires terminal support for the escape sequence. Cmd doesn’t support it.

Comment: This isn't about the escape sequence though, the "Move 4 lines down" code is the broken part

Comment: @Hydrough as already mentioned, cmd doesn't support escape sequences, therefore it is quite normal that your code doesn't work in cmd. Installing . NET Framework won't help, it's totally unrelated. Switching to another compiler won't of course help either.

Comment: @Hydrough "\033[4B" is the escape sequence for "move 4 lines down". So if your terminal doesn't support escape sequences, your code appears to be broken. The problem cannot be repaired within your code.

Comment: Alright, well that's a bummer. Is there a way to relocate the cursor with code in CMD or will I have to get a different program to run the code? What's the solution?

Comment: @Hydrough you need a terminal that supports ANSI escape codes, period. Or you need to write your program using the Windows graphic interface, but that's another, very different story.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/how-to-make-win32-console-recognize-ansi-vt100-escape-sequences

Comment: @MarkTolonen that's not true. cmd is a **shell**, like bash, ksh, powershell... Shell don't do anything with the ANSI sequence. Only conhost.exe, Windows terminal, xterm... are terminals. cmd will attach to some terminal when running, and [modern conhost.exe supports ANSI sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) although it's a bad terminal and one should use Windows terminal anyway

Comment: @phuclv Yes terminology.  The cmd *shell* doesn't enable terminal support for escape sequences *by default*.

Comment: @MarkTolonen no, the **console/terminal** which is conhost.exe doesn't enable ANSI sequence by default. It has nothing to do with cmd. Windows terminal supports it and should be used instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console doesn't enable virtual terminal sequences by default.  It requires extra code:

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void) {
    HANDLE h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD mode;
    GetConsoleMode(h, &mode);
    mode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
    SetConsoleMode(h, mode);

    char str[] = "text"; // Declare string
    printf("%s", str);   // Print string
    printf("\033[4B");   // Move down 4 lines;
    printf("%s", str);   // Print string
    _getch();
}
```

Output (cmd):

```
text



    text
```

Comment: Oh thank you this work so well thank you so much! A project I spent 2+ weeks on is not lost after all, all thanks to you!

Comment: `GetConsoleMode` already implies that it has to do with the console, not the shell (cmd or powershell)