# Calling to system function in C causes it to fix ANSI colors?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, cmd

I've been making tools for the command line for a little while now. However, one thing that stuck out to me when I was going over some old projects was this:

```cpp
// I ABSOLUTELY NEED THIS BUT IDK WHY!!!!
system("Title Something");
```

So I decided to investigate. When I removed it and ran the tool again in a simulated environment (more specifically VSCodes simulated console) everything seemed fine. However when I tried running it in cmd I saw that all of the colors that I had previously used in my code where broken.

So I pulled up a temporary projects like this one:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  printf("\033[1;31mI am red!\033[0m");
}
```

And when I ran it I got:

```
C:\tests\ANSI-test>hello
←[1;31mI am red!←[0m
```

Which was similar to what I had previously gotten with my other tool. And so I added back the seemingly random `system("Title Something");` line (making sure I included stdlib.h):

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
  system("Title Something");
  printf("\033[1;31mI am red!\033[0m");
}
```

And I got color working again!:

```
C:\tests\ANSI-test>hello
I am red!                                                   (pretend this is red)
```

I'm not sure exactly what causes this, I have a couple of speculations:

- the system function initializes something to do with the console, which triggers the working of ANSI colors
- system somehow calls to WinAPI and tells it to use colors inside the terminal

I did try searching for this but I didn't really find anything related to it other than this:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/how-to-make-win32-console-recognize-ansi-vt100-escape-sequences-in-c#:~:text=Starting%20from%20Windows%2010%20TH2,they%20have%20to%20be%20enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/how-to-make-win32-console-recognize-ansi-vt100-escape-sequences-in-c#:%7E:text=Starting%20from%20Windows%2010%20TH2,they%20have%20to%20be%20enabled)).

Comment: *the system function initializes something to do with the console...* `Title Something` changes the title of the console window to `Something`.

Comment: Yes, @WeatherVane Indeed it does. But I was mostly refering to what *besides* running the command, the system function does. Maybe it initializes ANSI coloring? Not exactly sure. Thats why I didn't specify anything

Comment: @WeatherVane interesting,,  I was never aware of the `title` command!

Comment: @RemyLebeau neither was I! I wondered about passing *seemingly random `system("Title Something");`* and found it. From small seeds trees grow, and it led me to discover the colour settings for Windows' `cmd.exe` shell. I have two routes: one sets the environment for an older 32-bit MSVC, the other is for a recent 64-bit version. So when both consoles are running, as can happen, I can now immediately see which is which.

Comment: @DimiturKarabuyukov Have you seen my answer to your question here? I believe it should answer your question precisely, in which case you should accept it. If something about it is unclear and does not answer your question, you can leave a comment and I will try to edit it to be better. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @DouglasB . I totally forgot about the question. Yes, the answer is in fact correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting find. From what I am able to gather, `system()` seems to set the `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` flag (I am not sure if it does this before or after forking, but thinking about it more, I don't think this would matter since its setting it for the entire console handle). I find it interesting because this does not seem to be the default for that flag (new cmd.exe launch with it disabled, so its technically opt-in). Im really not sure why this behavior would be intended, but you can see that it is the case by running the following expanded example with 0-2 args:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
    // Get handle of current stdout
    HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD dwMode = 0;

    if (__argc == 2) {
        printf("Running with system call\n");
        system("Title Something");
    }
    else if (__argc == 3) {
        printf("Running with console flag set\n");
        GetConsoleMode(hOut, &dwMode);
        dwMode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
        SetConsoleMode(hOut, dwMode);
    }

    // Check if the flag is set before printing
    GetConsoleMode(hOut, &dwMode);
    if (dwMode & ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING) {
        printf("Virtual terminal processing is enabled!\n");
    }
    printf("\033[1;31mI am red!\033[0m");
}
```

I think from that you can also see how to avoid using `system()` to kludge the virtual console flag and just directly set it. Its unfortunate that this particular behavior is not well documented but I hope this at least helps clear it up.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is a really interesting question and I actually didn't find anything that gives great insights while I was digging. However, there might be some things worth mentioning:

On [CPP-Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system) they say the following:

> Calls the host environment's command processor with the parameter
> command. Returns an implementation-defined value (usually the value
> that the invoked program returns).

So it seems that the invocation of the `system()` function is entirely `implementation-defined`.

Note how they say `"possible output"` in the example below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
 
int main(void) {
    system("date +%A");
    system("gcc --version");
}

Possible output:

Wednesday
gcc (GCC) 11.2.0
...
```

On [cplusplus.com](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) they give a similar statement:

> The effects of invoking a command depend on the system and library
> implementation, and may cause a program to behave in a non-standard
> manner or to terminate.

So I conclude:

The `system()`-function invokes the shell of the operating system, which in turn may have its own *initialization routines*.

Regarding the initialization of the *console environment in Windows*, the behavior can be influenced by various factors, including the `specific version` of Windows and the `configuration settings` of the command prompt.

I don't think that the initialization process is well-documented in relation to the system function. I hope this helps (even though I'm not entirely sure myself).

Comment: Thats really interesting. I'll definately have to checkout the website. It really does seem really weird how that works - I'm sure it has to do with compatability with old versions of windows that didn't support ASCI. Maybe involking the system causes the terminal to think "yep, I have support for colors". Thanks for all of the intel!