# Windows API Virtual Terminal Processing with SetConsoleMode & WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW not working?

Tags: c++, windows, console-application

I have implemented a function named 'drawText', which does as it says, it draws text to the console screen.

```
inline std::string colorize(const std::string& str, COLOR fg, COLOR bg)
{
    return fg + (bg + str) + COLOR_RESET;
}
inline void drawText(int x, int y, int end, const std::string& text, COLOR fg = NULL, COLOR bg = NULL) {

    HANDLE console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    size_t offset = 0;
    size_t index = text.find('\n');
    do {
        if (end != NULL && y == end) break;
        COORD pos = { static_cast<SHORT>(x), static_cast<SHORT>(y) };
        DWORD written;


        // Set text attributes (color)

        // Write characters to the console
        std::string sub = (fg != NULL || bg != NULL) ? colorize(text.substr(offset, index - offset), fg, bg) : text.substr(offset, index - offset);
        int requiredSize = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, sub.c_str(), -1, nullptr, 0);

        // Allocate memory for the wide string
        LPWSTR wtext = new WCHAR[requiredSize];

        // Convert narrow string to wide string
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, sub.c_str(), -1, wtext, requiredSize);
        WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW(console, wtext, static_cast<DWORD>(sub.length()), pos, &written);

        // Reset text attributes

        offset = index + 1;
        index = text.find('\n', offset);


        delete[] wtext;
        y++;
    } while (index != std::string::npos);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(console, FOREGROUND_WHITE | BACKGROUND_BLACK);
}
```

I'm trying to print the COLOR (`typedef const char* COLOR;`) types before and after the string. Which just spits the escape codes onto the screen. I've tried using the `SetConsoleTextAttribute` function, yet that yields no result as well. I really don't have much info on this since the API here for me is quite hard to debug. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

here are my escape codes:

```
#define FG_BOLD_BLACK "\033[1;30m"
#define FG_BOLD_RED "\033[1;31m"
#define FG_BOLD_GREEN "\033[1;32m"
#define FG_BOLD_YELLOW "\033[1;33m"
#define FG_BOLD_BLUE "\033[1;34m"
#define FG_BOLD_MAGENTA "\033[1;35m"
#define FG_BOLD_CYAN "\033[1;36m"
#define FG_BOLD_WHITE "\033[1;37m"

#define FG_BLACK      "\x1B[30m"
#define FG_RED        "\x1B[31m"
#define FG_GREEN      "\x1B[32m"
#define FG_YELLOW     "\x1B[33m"
#define FG_BLUE       "\x1B[34m"
#define FG_MAGENTA    "\x1B[35m"
#define FG_CYAN       "\x1B[36m"
#define FG_WHITE      "\x1B[37m"
// Console Background Colors
#define BG_BLACK "\033[40m"
#define BG_RED "\033[41m"
#define BG_GREEN "\033[42m"
#define BG_YELLOW "\033[43m"
#define BG_BLUE "\033[44m"
#define BG_MAGENTA "\033[45m"
#define BG_CYAN "\033[46m"
#define BG_WHITE "\033[47m"

// Console Bold Background Colors
#define BG_BOLD_BLACK "\033[1;40m"
#define BG_BOLD_RED "\033[1;41m"
#define BG_BOLD_GREEN "\033[1;42m"
#define BG_BOLD_YELLOW "\033[1;43m"
#define BG_BOLD_BLUE "\033[1;44m"
#define BG_BOLD_MAGENTA "\033[1;45m"
#define BG_BOLD_CYAN "\033[1;46m"
#define BG_BOLD_WHITE "\033[1;47m"
#define COLOR_RESET      "\x1B[0m"
typedef const char* COLOR;
```

Comment: Recommendation: Bundle this up into a [mre] to make it more accessible to future askers (and present answerers).

Comment: Do you really need all of this code to show an `int main()` that simply calls 2 or 3 Console API functions with a hard-coded string to duplicate the issue?

Comment: [How to make win32 console recognize ANSI/VT100 escape sequences in \`c\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35864976) maybe??

Comment: If you think about it, why did you expect your code to work "out of box"?  What if someone actually wanted to print `"\x1B[0m"`, for whatever reason?  Why would this automatically switch on ANSI, when the person actually wanted to see a potential weird character followed by `[0m` on the console?  As the link that @001 shows, it seems you have to "opt-in" to get ANSI to work.